# Best way to transform data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vendor

I have a vendor API call in my nodejs app that returns various objects, with the below being an example of one object in the the JSON:

```
[{
"id": 365467865567,
"type": "PERSON",
"created_time": 1492809120,
"updated_time": 1492809542,
"last_contacted": 1492809128,
"properties": [
    {
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "phone",
    "value": "123456789"
    },
    {
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "first_name",
    "value": "Test2"
    },
    {
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "last_name",
    "value": "You"
    },
    {
    "type": "CUSTOM",
    "name": "utm_medium",
    "value": "email"
    }
]
}]
```

Its not very easy to use the data in this format, and need to transpose it to a key,value format. Something similar to:

```
[{
"id": 365467865567,
"type": "PERSON",
"created_time": 1492809120,
"updated_time": 1492809542,
"last_contacted": 1492809128,
"properties":
    {
    "phone": "123456789",
    "first_name": "Test2",
    "last_name": "You",
    "utm_medium": "email"
    }
}]
```

What would be the most efficient way to transform this?

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not looking for the most *efficient* way to do this, but instead for *any* way you can do this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping over the properties and reassigning the variable.

```
var array = [{
  "id": 365467865567,
  "type": "PERSON",
  "created_time": 1492809120,
  "updated_time": 1492809542,
  "last_contacted": 1492809128,
  "properties": [{
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "phone",
    "value": "123456789"
  }, {
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "first_name",
    "value": "Test2"
  }, {
    "type": "SYSTEM",
    "name": "last_name",
    "value": "You"
  }, {
    "type": "CUSTOM",
    "name": "utm_medium",
    "value": "email"
  }]
}];

array.forEach(function(obj) {
  var properties = {};
  obj.properties.forEach(function(prop) {
    properties[prop.name] = prop.value;
  });
  obj.properties = properties;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hycg5r80/3/

Comment: A `for` and a nested `forEach`? - that's a bit.. unorthodox - why not 2 `for` or just 2 `forEach` instead?

Comment: I'll fix that. Mostly because I didn't realize the json object was an array at first (my mistake).

Answer (score 2):

here's a way, idk if most efficient but it's short n sweet.

```
thing[0].properties = thing[0].properties.reduce( (p, n) => ( 
  n[p.name] = p.value;
  return n;
), {});
```